# Publish to AWS IoT topic from C#

Tags: c#, aws-iot

Can I use C# to publish a JSON object to an AWS IoT topic without using the official SDK? Basically, I'd like to replicate what I can do from Postman, i.e. send POST/PUT/GET requests to AWS IoT URLs.

Ideally, I'd like to use the HTTP(S) protocol instead of MQTT for simplicity.

Comment: Question: why do you need to simplify? Is this for a hobby project, or for a larger one? MQTT is very lightweight so going through HTTPS is going to increase server load.

Comment: Hi @Slothario, this is for a test tool that will be used by service technicians every now and then. They are usually not computer sayyy and I cannot ask them to use Postman.

Comment: That's fair. It's actually quite simple though to subscribe and publish directly to MQTT topics, probably simpler than HTTP if less familiar. Do whatever works and whatever's easiest for you, but if I were in your shoes I'd just get a C#  MQTT library (forgot what I used last time) and subscribe and publish directly to the topic. Also you should be aware there are a lot of great free programs that will let you view and publish to MQTT that you can use for your own testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You will need only some C# library that implements one of the AWS IoT available protocols, such MQTT. In the first semester of 2018, I tested the AWS IoT through a basic application in Python, using the publish and subscribe methods, publishing some data and receiving these data through notifications. You can take a look [here, in this link](https://github.com/cezane/awsiot/blob/master/awsiot-publish.py). I used [Paho MQTT](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/), which is an MQTT client library that enable applications to connect to an MQTT broker, publish data and subscribe to topics, receiving data through notifications.

I think you can try M2Mqtt in your C# application:

- https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/dotnet/
- https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.m2mqtt